# How to disable database initialization with Spring-Cloud-Skipper

Tags: spring-cloud-skipper

I'm trying to disable the initialization of tables in Spring-Cloud-Skipper. Is there a property much like the spring.cloud.dataflow.rdbms.initialize.enable=false in Spring-Cloud-Dataflow that I can set? If not, how do I disable the initialization of the tables?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Cloud Skipper uses Spring Boot's Hibernate JPA configurations to setup database initialization and Flyway properties to perform database migrations.

Hence, you can pass the following properties to disable database initialization during the Spring Cloud Skipper server startup:

```
 --spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none --spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

Comment: when i add above to application properties Getting error on skipper startup
       Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SKIPPER_REPOSITORY" not found; SQL statement:

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using streams you can disable the stream feature which will stop the skipper server configuration from loading when spring data flow server is starting

add below configuration in your application.properties

`spring.flyway.enabled=false`

`spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false`

Hope this helps :)